# How to vary boxplot width when making custom quantiles?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, width, boxplot

I wanted to set the length of the boxplot whiskers to be the median of the data +/- 1.96*standard deviation (aka the 95% distribution of the data). I did this by calculating the boxplot statistics using aggregate and setting those to be the minimum, lower quartile, median, etc. How can I set the boxplot width to vary so that it is proportional to the square root of the number of observations (like ggplot does with varwidth = TRUE)? Anything I currently try (setting weight, width) varies the width of all of the categories equally. Thank you.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

residuals <- runif(n=1000, min=-3, max=3)
category <- c('A','A','A','B','B','C','D','E','E','F')
df1 <- data.frame(category,residuals)


boxplot_stats <- aggregate(residuals ~ category, df1, function(x) {
  median_val = median(x)
  z_score = 1.96
  min_quantile = median_val - z_score * sd(x)
  lower_quantile = quantile(x, c(0.25))
  upper_quantile = quantile(x, c(0.75))
  max_quantile = median_val + z_score * sd(x)
  n_obs_sqrt = sqrt(length(x))
  c(min_quantile, lower_quantile, median_val, upper_quantile, max_quantile, n_obs_sqrt)
})

custom_boxplot <- ggplot(boxplot_stats, aes(x=category))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = residuals[, 1], lower = residuals[, 2], middle = residuals[, 3], upper = residuals[, 4], ymax = residuals[, 5]), stat = "identity", color = "black",fill="lightblue") +
  labs(title="boxplot",x="Category",y="Residuals") + 
  theme_bw()
print(custom_boxplot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not necessary (see footnote), the more idiomatic way to do this would be to use `summarize` instead of `aggregate` so that you can have distinct column names rather than matrix columns used inside ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

boxplot_stats <- df1 %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(median_val     = median(residuals),
            min_quantile   = median_val - 1.96 * sd(residuals),
            lower_quantile = quantile(residuals, c(0.25)),
            upper_quantile = quantile(residuals, c(0.75)),
            max_quantile   = median_val + 1.96 * sd(residuals),
            n_obs_sqrt     = sqrt(n()))

boxplot_stats
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   category median_val min_quantile lower_quantile upper_quantile max_quantile
#>   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 A            0.0247        -3.44         -1.34           1.66          3.49
#> 2 B           -0.166         -3.43         -1.43           1.38          3.10
#> 3 C           -0.445         -3.59         -1.67           0.905         2.70
#> 4 D           -0.443         -3.70         -1.84           0.971         2.81
#> 5 E           -0.0109        -3.44         -1.35           1.53          3.41
#> 6 F            0.739         -2.82         -0.985          1.84          4.30
#> # i 1 more variable: n_obs_sqrt <dbl>
```

Because `width` is not an aesthetic mapping, you need to ensure that the *actual desired widths* are plotted. None of these should be larger than 1 (otherwise the boxes will overlap), so the correct expression for `widths` would be `boxplot_stats$n_obs_sqrt/max(boxplot_stats$n_obs_sqrt)`. You also need to ensure you specify `position = position_dodge` to get them to line up correctly:

```r
ggplot(boxplot_stats, aes(x = category)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin   = min_quantile, lower = lower_quantile,
                   middle = median_val,   upper = upper_quantile, 
                   ymax   = max_quantile, weight = n_obs_sqrt), 
               width = boxplot_stats$n_obs_sqrt/max(boxplot_stats$n_obs_sqrt),
               stat = "identity",
               color = "black", fill = "lightblue", 
               position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(title = "boxplot", x = "Category", y = "Residuals") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

**Footnote**

If for some reason you can't use `dplyr` then the equivalent using your `aggregate` output would be:

```r
ggplot(boxplot_stats, aes(category)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = residuals[, 1],   lower = residuals[, 2], 
                   middle = residuals[, 3], upper = residuals[, 4], 
                   ymax = residuals[, 5]), 
               stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "lightblue", 
               width = boxplot_stats$residuals[,6]/
                         max(boxplot_stats$residuals[,6]),
               position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(title = "boxplot", x = "Category", y = "Residuals") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. First you need to compile the number of observations:

```
df1 %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

and then put these into the width argument

```
custom_boxplot <- ggplot(boxplot_stats, aes(x=category))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = residuals[, 1], lower = residuals[, 2], middle = residuals[, 3], 
                   upper = residuals[, 4], ymax = residuals[, 5]), 
               stat = "identity", color = "black",fill="lightblue",
               width = sqrt(c(300,200,100,100,200,100))) +
  labs(title="boxplot",x="Category",y="Residuals") + 
  theme_bw()
print(custom_boxplot)
```

I suspect there is a more programmatic way to do this than hard coding but hopefully this gives you a start

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct plot. The boxes are far larger than the distance between tick marks, are not aligned with the x axis, and are not evenly spaced. To be fair, the proportional widths are correct, but the result isn't really a usable plot.